# You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved

Tags: azure-databricks

I am using DataBricks as a service on Azure. This is my cluster info :

[image]

I ran below command and everythings was o.

```
 %sql
 Select 
    * 
 from db_xxxxx.t_fxxxxxxxxx
 limit 10
```

Then I have updated some rows in above table. When I run above command again i have this error :

```
    Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 2823.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 2823.0 (TID 158824, 10.11.49.6, executor 14): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file abfss:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@storxfadev0501.dfs.core.windows.net/xsi-ed-faits/t_fait_xxxxxxxxxxx/_delta_log/00000000000000000022.json. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:640)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HEAD https://storxfadev0501.dfs.core.windows.net/devdledxsi01/xsi-ed-faits/t_fait_photo_impact/_delta_log/00000000000000000022.json?timeout=90
    StatusCode=404
    StatusDescription=The specified path does not exist.
    ErrorCode=
    ErrorMessage=
        at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:912)
        at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.open(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
        at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FileSystemWithMetrics.open(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$.readFile(JsonDataSource.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(JsonFileFormat.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(JsonFileFormat.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:235)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: HEAD https://storxfadev0501.dfs.core.windows.net/devdledxsi01/xsi-ed-faits/t_fait_photo_impact/_delta_log/00000000000000000022.json?timeout=90
    StatusCode=404
    StatusDescription=The specified path does not exist.
    ErrorCode=
    ErrorMessage=
        at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:134)
        at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In summary, you can either **refresh the table** (previous to execution ) name or **restart the cluster**

```py
spark.sql("refresh TABLE schema.table")
```

> It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can
> explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE
> tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
> involved. If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been
> removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the
> cluster.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour when you update some rows in the table and immediately querying the table.

From the error message: `It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.`

To resolve this issue, refresh all cached entries that are associated with the table.

```
REFRESH TABLE [db_name.]table_name
```

Refresh all cached entries associated with the table. If the table was previously cached, then it would be cached lazily the next time it is scanned.

Comment: this answer did not work for me. I refreshed my table but i had still the same problem. I restarted my cluster and after that everythings was ok. 
I will give you thumbs up.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the catalog cache using **clearCache()** worked for me before running the select query without restarting the Databricks cluster.

My observation is that, this issue occurs when the table created has underlying Parquet files/Delta. The first time Spark reads the table, the Parquet files are cached. And if the underlying files are externally deleted/modified, this issue occurs when Spark tries to still read the cached file for accelerated read.

Use the following before reading the table
`spark.catalog.clearCache()`

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the updated Spark version. I was initially working with Spark 3.1.1, and despite attempting various solutions, I couldn't resolve the error. I recommend updating to the latest version. In my case, I upgraded to Spark 3.4.1, and it worked seamlessly without requiring any code changes. All caching issues were automatically addressed.
I hope this information proves helpful to you! :)